# How to show dialogue if url contains something

Tags: javascript

If my URL is any of these type:

1. `domain.com/page.html?refer=whatsapp`
2. `domain.com/page.html#whatsapp`

Then I want to show a dialogue that shows "You have been referred from Whatsapp". 
And if the url is accessed without the whatsapp part, then it must not show the dialoge box.

What I have tried is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = window.location.href;

    if (url.search("#wa") >= 0) {
        //found it, now do something
    } 
    alert("Good Afternoon");
} else {
    null //if not just do nothing
}
</script>
```

But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

It helps you

```js
var url = window.location.href;

// For example. In real app remove it
url = 'http://website.com/page.html#whatsapp';

// Search our #ID
var source = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('#') + 1);

// For salutation text
var salutation = null;

// Iterate variants
switch ( source ) {
  case 'whatsapp' : salutation = 'You have been referred from Whatsapp'; break;
  default : salutation = 'unknown website';
}


alert ( salutation );
```